# How to create a horizontal drawer?

Tags: java, android

How do I create a horizontal drawer in Android? I have a button which is supposed to show a navbar which slides from the top like a drawer. How do I achieve this? I am new to Android guys, please help.

Comment: The way SO works is that you try a solution, and show what you've tried before asking a question. Did you google for existing solutions already?

Comment: I did. I was thinking if I could do it with fragments but I do not know where to start or if it's even possible. I am new to Android so I do not know what to search for.

Comment: please refer this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer)

Comment: That's not what I want. I want it coming from the top

Comment: you can do from bottom to top slide up using default bottom menu provided by android support library.

Comment: refer this link (https://abhiandroid.com/ui/slidingdrawer)